# Is it bad to have functions return strings instead of ints? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, function, int, return

I'm still relatively new to programming. I'm in the process of working on a game with SDL and I find myself wondering where or not I am using bad habits.

For example, I have a function called titleScreen(), where the user decides which mode of the game to enter.

I can either return a value from 0-3, then process it through an if/else/else/else statement to decide what mode they selected.

**or**

I can return a string such as "STORYMODE", "FREEPLAY", "TUTORIAL", or "QUIT" and use that to decide which mode.

I like the second mode because it eliminates the initital confusion on trying to figure out which mode was selected, but I have a feeling in the back of my head that there is a problem doing it that way.

In my situation, what is the best way to return a value?

Answer (score 8):

In this case you should use `enum` listing all states to achieve readability without performance hit.
For example:

```
enum  mode {
    STORYMODE,
    FREEPLAY,
    TUTORIAL,
    QUIT
}
```

Comment: It's not just about a performance hit - it's also (at least cosmetically) giving a type to your set of possible values. In C++11 it's actually strongly typed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use enums for that, that is actually int but just more readable.
So I would create:

```
enum GameMode { STORYMODE, FREEPLAY, TUTORIAL, QUIT };
```

And have method return type GameMode.

**EDIT 2:**

If you have buttons for every game mode, just return enum or call some other method with enum parameter when button is clicked. Same way as you are doing now with string.

Comment: Where exactly would I put the declaration for the enum, then? In main before the function is called? Or is that enum considered a function of its own?

Comment: Ah, I haven't understood you question well than. So you have those values as input in console?

Comment: Thank you for you reply and thanks for bearing with me. 

I'm doing an SDL application, so I have main.cpp, function.h, and function.cpp as my files. My main function calls init(), loadFiles(), and then should call titlescreen(). Titlescreen() should return the enum value, but I'm not sure if I'd want to write that enum line in main, in the titlescreen() function, or as it's own line in the function.h and function.cpp files.

I apologize, I am quite new to all of this and while I am learning by book, I can't help but try to tackle on goals that I am not prepared for.

Comment: I edited my answer, so you can take a look and see whether that solves you problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it's not console. The user actually has an 800x600 application window with images and buttons. The user clicks on a button with a mouse (this part works) and the click should return the gamemode value.

Comment: Then you just return GameMode enumeration there.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning a shared pointer to a game object? Below is some pseudo code to get you started and whatever calls `titleScreen` should call `operator()` on the returned object.

```
class GameI {
public:
    virtual ~GameI() {};
    void operator() = 0;
}

typedef std::shared_ptr<GameI> SharedGame;

class GameStory {
public:
    void operator();
}

void GameStory::operator()
{
    ...
}

SharedGame titleScreen()
{
    ...
    return SharedGame(new GameStory());
}
```